# Why wordpress rewrite my custom URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am new in wordpress
There may a mapping question in my website

I hope this SEO URL is work and get Post data:
http://domain/web/d-post/M00069/TomLi

If not using SEO URL(get action), it is work!
http://domain/web/d-post?d_id=M00069&d_name=TomLi
http://domain/web/d-post/?d_id=M00069&d_name=TomLi
http://domain/web?pagename=d-post&d_id=M00069&d_name=TomLi
http://domain/web/?pagename=d-post&d_id=M00069&d_name=TomLi

In this case
http://domain/web/d-post/M00069/TomLi
but why my page will redirect to:
http://domain/web/d-post/

Should I set or change something that can make my URL work? 
Thanks a lot

## In .htaccess

```
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteRule ^d-post/([A-Z0-9]+)/(.*)/$ ?pagename=d-post&d_id=$1&d_name=$2 [L]
#
```

Without using wp & run at localhost it is work
[image: If not using wordpress]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I find I should add some filter

```
add_filter('query_vars','d_search_1');
function d_search_1($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'd_id');
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i clearly understood you want to change permalink. you can set any type of permalink in admin menu > settings >permalinks.

Comment: You can't set this kind of search URL in the permalinks option page.

Comment: wordpress permalinks setting not suitable for case, 
I use plugin to make this page(d-search)

Answer (score 0):

Try by this.

```
function myff() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    
    if ( !isset( $wp_rewrite ) || !is_object( $wp_rewrite ) || !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        return;
    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/search/") === false && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url() . "/search/" . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit;
    }   
}
 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'myff' );
```

Or through .htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: thanks, but it looks not working